# Random ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on android phone orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

We are getting the below error when we change the android phone orientation. Currently testing this in android v 5 and 4.4.4. Our app is locked to portrait. So if we twist the phone to landscape mode, the view will  not get changed but remain in portrait mode.

This exception is thrown and the app crashes when we change the phone orientation to landscape. This will not be able to replicate always. But once in 10 or 15 times, app crashes with the below error. Even if it is random, this can be replicated constantly. Might be if we twist the phone at any particular time but not sure. I frequently get this when I twist the phone during the login or logout actions which takes a couple of seconds to complete these actions.

This exception is not thrown from a particular activity or piece of code. As i mentioned in the post this is thrown when i change phone orientation on any view once in 10 or 15 times random. But will not be able to replicate constantly.

Below is the full stacktrace.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-2147483648
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.groupArcsByFirstVertex(GridLayout.java:1413)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis$1.<init>(GridLayout.java:1432)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.topologicalSort(GridLayout.java:1429)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.topologicalSort(GridLayout.java:1468)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.createArcs(GridLayout.java:1502)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getArcs(GridLayout.java:1516)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeLocations(GridLayout.java:1687)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getLocations(GridLayout.java:1708)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1729)
at android.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1740)
at android.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:1056)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16557)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.sys
```

Comment: Show the code where you're getting this exception.

Comment: Please share your code. Its probably because you are decreasing or increasing the array pointer in onCreate and it runs out of bounds of the array size.

Comment: This exception is not thrown from a particular activity or piece of code. As i mentioned in the post this is thrown when i change phone orientation on any view once in 10 or 15 times random. But will not be able to replicate constantly.

Comment: Everybody please read the stack trace, this is not a silly question as you might guess from the title.

Comment: Is that exception always on the GridView and are you doing anything funny with it programmatically or maybe you have subclassed GridView?

Comment: Not always on GridView.

Answer (score -1):

You could override onConfigurationChanged in your activity and update your array each time the orientation is changed.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // Update your array here
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // Update your array here
    }
}
```

You need to also android:configChanges to your activity:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

This code will stop restarting your activity when the orientation is changed. However this may not work as I do not know what your code is like.

Comment: This exception is not thrown from a particular activity or piece of code. As i mentioned in the post this is thrown when i change phone orientation on any view once in 10 or 15 times random. But will not be able to replicate constantly.

Comment: So this I assume is happening all throughout your application?

Comment: Yes.This is happening throughout the application. but randomly not always.